# Keycloak addUser inside custom Authenticator getting error

Tags: keycloak, custom-authentication

Here is my not finished source that will do some "checks" then addUser if not exist,
Currently I'm testing simply adding new user here is my writings

```java
public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
    KeycloakSession session = context.getSession();
    RealmModel realm = context.getRealm();

    String username = "hello";
    UserProvider users = session.userLocalStorage();
    UserModel user = users.getUserByUsername(realm,username);
    if (user == null) {
        logger.infof("addingUser");
        user = session.users().addUser(realm,username);
        logger.infof("isEnabled()");
        user.setEnabled(true);
        user.setEmail("mail@mail.com");
        user.setEmailVerified(true);
    }    
    context.setUser(user);       
    context.success();
}
```

with this source when I try to login for the first time, it gets me error but user is created.
Then if I try to login for the second time, it logs in successfully (shows me personal page)

```
06:05:12,633 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-8) 
Unique index or primary 
key violation: "UK_RU8TT6T700S9V50BU18WS5HA6_INDEX_B ON PUBLIC.USER_ENTITY(REALM_ID, 
USERNAME) VALUES ('Customer', 'hello', 5)"; SQL statement:
2021-11-12T06:05:12.634069100Z insert into USER_ENTITY (CREATED_TIMESTAMP, EMAIL, 
EMAIL_CONSTRAINT, EMAIL_VERIFIED, ENABLED, FEDERATION_LINK, 
FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, NOT_BEFORE, REALM_ID, SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_LINK, USERNAME, 
ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-197]
2021-11-12T06:05:12.647493900Z
```

Additional information logs show me output twice for example

```
2021-11-12T06:05:12.610917800Z 06:05:12,610 INFO  [class name] (default task-6) addingUser
2021-11-12T06:05:12.615587600Z 06:05:12,615 INFO  [class name] (default task-8) addingUser
```

task 6 reaches log output **logger.infof("isEnabled()");**

task 8 not